Teensy 4.1 audio cuts out when motor moves
I have a Big Mouth Billy Bass project, using a Teensy 4.1, teensy audio shield connected to speaker through line out to an amp, and two MX1508 motor controllers to control the body and mouth motors.  Code is here https://github.com/ambrice/billybigmouth/blob/main/billybigmouth.ino
I'm starting the save with AudioPlaySdWav play() and that works, and while that's playing I can run MX1508 motorGo() on one of the motors and audio plays.  But if I move the head and then use motorGo() on the mouth motor, the audio stops playing for the time when the mouth is being moved.  It picks up later in the song after, so it's like it was on mute during that time.  I assume there's an issue with playing audio and driving two PWMs at the same time, how do I get all three working at the same time?

Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour]to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to provide details, like a minimal, complete(!), and reproducible example sketch. Since you suspect "interference" between audio and PWM, it is especially important to know the details.

There is a link to the complete code with all the details in the question

Please learn how this site works. Questions are supposed to be self-contained, that means include the [mre] directly. External resources tend to vanish, and this is not a forum.
